# compile a c++ , at project with libcurl library on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, libcurl

I work on an open source c++ project to test some changes, and try to add curl to it. the project has it's own `autogen.sh` script and will create a `configure`, I'm not familiar so much with `autogen` and `configure` script but I can find some where to add `-libcurl` to it. 
it easy to compile for Linux based os, but when I want to build it on windows, have to build `curl` from source code and reference it to code, also I able to build it for windows.
But finally I try to build it on mac, I can't find how can I link `libcurl` to mac, I try to build from source code no success.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

in Makefile script I have these :

```
CFLAGS = -DCURL_STATICLIB

CURL_CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/Cellar/libcurl/include/

CURL_LIBS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/libcurl/lib -lcurl

OBJCXXFLAGS = -DCURL_STATICLIB
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Those paths ('/usr/local/Cellar/') belong to Homebrew. [Install it](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) on your Mac if you don't have it yet. It is the easiest way to bring many open source libraries to your mac. It is easily managed from the command line, but there are also GUI utilities like [Cakebrew](https://www.cakebrew.com/).

Once you have Homebrew installed, you only need to do this at your terminal  to install libcurl:

```
brew install curl
```

It installs both the static and the dynamic library at `/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/`.

When installing the package, it outputs this text:

> curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because macOS already provides this software and installing another
>   cersion in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> For compilers to find curl you may need to set:
>
> ```
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"
> ```
>
> For pkg-config to find curl you may need to set:
>
> ```
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig"
> ```

There is also another brew package named 'curl-openssl' with openssl support.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I do that but again I have same error message.

Comment: And did you change your Makefile to match the real paths where `brew` installs the library?